# How to Convert some custom Map object to LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
Map<String, List<Address>> mapObj = someService.getSomeAddress();
```

Using above call I'm getting `mapObj` of type `Map<String, List<Address>>`

And I want to send `mapObj` as a parameter in a another method (that I cannot change) as a `LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap>>` which does some further processing.

Is there any way that I can solve this problem without affecting data inside `mapObj`?

Comment: Well, yes. You need to create a copy anyway. How an Address becomes a List<LinkedHashMap> is unclear, though. And what the order should be is unclear, too. And the fact that the method cares about the concrete type of the map is a smell, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to perform a couple of conversion steps.

1. Convert all `Address` objects to `LinkedHashMap` objects.
2. Put all `Map` entries into a `LinkedHashMap` object.

For 1st one, you can write a utility method some where that can do this conversion. For example,

```
public static List<LinkedHashMap> addresstoMap(List<Address> addresses)
{
    List<LinkedHashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Address a: addresses){
        LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();
        // Add address fields to map here
        list.add(map);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then, for the 2nd step, you can do this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap>> map = new LinkedHashMap<?,?>();
```

iterate through the entry sets of `mapObj` and put them into the above `map` object.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Address>> e : m.entrySet()) {
    map.put(e.getKey(), addresstoMap(e.getValue()));
}
```

The final `map` object above will contain the correct representation in the `LinkedHashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap>>` datatype.

Hope this helps!